# Помогите найти ошибку в программе

Tags: pascal

Дана последовательность символов, имеющая следующий вид d1+-d2+-...+-dn(все d-цифры, n>1). Вычислить значение выражения. Проблема в плане того, что при вводе чисел выдает неверные ответы.

```
var
  s,s1:char;
  k:byte;
  sum,raz:integer;
begin
  k:=0;
  sum:=0;
  raz:=0;
  Repeat
    read(s);
    if s <> ' ' then
    Begin
      if (s>='0')and (s<='9') then
        sum:=sum+(ord(s)-ord('0'));
      k:=k+1;
      if k=1 then 
        s1:=s;
    end;
  Until s=#13;
  raz:=(-1) *(sum-2*(ord(s1)-ord('0')));
  writeln(raz);
end.
```

Comment: Приведите парочку примеров ввода и вывода для задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не пренебрегайте `begin` и `end`, даже если они обрамляют одну строчку. 
Форматирование кода тоже полезно.

```
if s <> ' ' then
Begin
  if (s>='0')and (s<='9') then
  begin
    sum:=sum+(ord(s)-ord('0'));
    k:=k+1;
    if k=1 then 
    begin
      s1:=s;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Не делайте работу за автора, постарайтесь лучше объяснить свой ответ